# Error when returning Observable in Angular

Tags: angular, http, observable

I have the following method where I make a post request to a REST API:

```
postTextToSentimentAnalysis(userTextInput: string): Observable<any> {
  let authenticatedUser = this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser();
  if (authenticatedUser == null) {
    return;
  }
  authenticatedUser.getSession( (err, session) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    const token = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', token);
    this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().getSession((err, session) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return;
      }
      const token = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      const headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Authorization', token);
      return this.httpClient.post('http://example.com:12445/sentiment-analysis/sentiment-analysis-function', userTextInput, { headers: {'Authorization': token} })});
  });
}
```

In the method where I call the function I want to subscribe to the Observable:

```
analyseText(){
console.log("Analyse Input: " + this.sentimentTextInput);
this.sentimentManagementService.postTextToSentimentAnalysis(this.sentimentTextInput).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  //this.sentimentTextResult = res;
}, error => {
  console.log(error);
});
}
```

When I call this function I get the following error:

```
SentimentAnalysisComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
at SentimentAnalysisComponent.analyseText (sentiment-analysis.component.ts:21)
at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (SentimentAnalysisComponent.html:6)
at handleEvent (core.js:43993)
at callWithDebugContext (core.js:45632)
at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:45247)
at dispatchEvent (core.js:29804)
at core.js:42925
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:2668)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39680)
```

Line 21 is where I call the subscribe() function.

```
getAuthenticatedUser() {
// gets the current user from the local storage
return userPool.getCurrentUser();
}
```

Comment: Make sure `postTextToSentimentAnalysis` always returns an Observable. Please post the code for `this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().getSession(..)`. And why do you have use this function twice where one call is inside the anothers callback?

Comment: @fridoo I use a project to use AWS cognito, so I can show you the getAutheticatedUser() method. And you are right, I called the getSession() method twice, which I just changed.

Comment: this isn't returning anything. what is the first getSession call returning? is that a promise?

Comment: @bryan60 I didnt write the getSession method. This method is provided from the project I use. But I get the point. I have to restructure the method to return the Observable.

Comment: It is very hard to read the code you posted and the code seems incomplete. Based on what you have posted, I would assume you are missing the `return` before `authenticatedUser.getSession` in your `postTextToSentimentAnalysis` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning an Observable in `postTextToSentimentAnalysis`.

Create an Observable that calls `this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().getSession` and emits the required resource in the callback. User `switchMap` to map that token to your http request.

```ts
getToken(): Observable<string> {
  return new Observable<string>(observer => {
    if (this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser() != null) {
      this.auth.getAuthenticatedUser().getSession((err, session) => {
        if (err) {
          observer.error(err);
          return;
        }
        observer.next(session.getIdToken().getJwtToken()); // emit token
        observer.complete();
      });
    } else {
      observer.complete(); // or observer.error('mymessage') if this is an error case
    }
  });
}

postTextToSentimentAnalysis(userTextInput: string): Observable<any> {
  return this.getToken().pipe(
    switchMap(token => this.httpClient.post(
      'http://example.com:12445/sentiment-analysis/sentiment-analysis-function', 
      userTextInput, 
      { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': token }) }
    ))
  );
}
```